# How to remove red highlight box in blender scene

Tags: modeling

So I just clicked something and created this Redbox that I cannot move, or recreate, and if I press ctrl Z it doesn't remove it. Is there a way to delete it? [image]

Comment: This is a render region (made by ctrl+b keys). To remove it ctrl+alt+b keys.

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: Hi, Mike, since this is a fix (great!) without needing an answer, and has been asked before, I think we can call it a duplicate.